# SSH Connection to a remote host that sits behind a NAT router

Tags: ssh

I wish to connect to a remote Ubuntu host. The remote host is in a different network behind NAT, so there is no direct access with a system-specific public IP address.

Simply trying to connect using `user@hostIP` results in a timeout, even though the host machine has the key saved.

How do I SSH into this remote host from my MacOS system?

Comment: *"all the devices connected to the machine get the same IP"* How's that supposed to work?

Comment: @Tetsujin - perhaps OP is describing NAT

Comment: Yes I think it's NAT, also I should have said host not remote in the title, so i changed it

Comment: then you'll need either to set a static IP on the remote machine you want to ssh in to, or set router that's doing the DHCP to assign a fixed IP to that machine, and then of course, you'd have some port forwarding happening already, right

Comment: do you suggest doing this vs using a VPN on the host machine ?

Comment: I re-worded your question so that it matches what you're describing; or how I understand it. Please verify and if I misunderstood your issue [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773682/edit) the question to correct. You're asking "how do I SSH in". New question "do you suggest VPN instead SSH" is a completely different ballgame, can't really be answered as the remote access can be accomplished with both approaches. Only you can determine which one is appropriate and can be realized in your situation.

Comment: I think the edits make sense. I asked the follow-up VPN question to ask what @JaromandaX, or anyone else, thinks about how easy either would be to setup. The SSH route or the VPN route.

Comment: You didn't state what your actual need is, and what's your access level on the remote network. If it's your home network, either one is possible fairly easily. Setting up SSH access to a single host is more straight-forward, as it doesn't require installing and configuring a new client, and doesn't affect the traffic forwarding of the local host. I hope my answer makes it clearer for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

[VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (Virtual Private Network) is an access method used when you need access to resources in an entire remote network (multiple hosts, printers, servers...). In essence your local system will then be part of the remote network and have a separate VPN tunnel IP address in the remote network IP range. Setting it up requires a VPN server in the remote network, and a VPN client on the local host.

Setting up a VPN is likely to cause access problems for the local resources, as VPN changes the local host's routing table; the default gateway changes to the remote network's gateway. For example you might not be able to use a local printer while the VPN is running. To overcome this the local network (or the individual IPs of the local resources) can be whitelisted in the VPN client settings. Alternatively local host's routing could be configured so that only the remote network is reachable through the VPN tunnel and all other networks through the local gateway router.

[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (Secure Shell) is probably the most common access method used when you need to access a single host in a remote network. Accessing the rest of the network resources is available through that remote host. SSH tunnel has no effect on the IP routes of the local host, so it can be done w/o hampering access to local network resources.

To get an SSH access into a remote host behind a NAT:

1. The remote host needs a static IP address. This can be either configured directly on the host, or it can be done by assigning a DHCP reservation for that host.
2. The router must be configured to forward ingress traffic to its public IP address with port used for SSH access (default 22) to the IP address of the remote host (Port Forwarding)
3. The remote host must have a running SSH server

If the remote router directly supports VPN access, it can be used to create the VPN. In that case installing and configuring a VPN client in the local host is sufficient. If it doesn't, the VPN server must be set up in a host inside the remote network, and the router must be configured similarly to forward the VPN traffic to that server.

If the need is just to access a single host, setting up SSH is more straigh-forward, as it doesn't require installing and configuring a new client, and doesn't affect the routing tables of the local host.

Answer (score 0):

> The remote machine is part of a network that doesn't assign a unique IP to each device, thus all the devices connected to the machine get the same IP.

The network *does* assign a unique IP to each device – only it's limited to inside of that network. The devices could not function without unique addresses.

"The same IP" as seen by the outside world is implemented by NAT, i.e. *translation* of the unique internal addresses to a shared external address. Usually that external address belongs to the NAT router/gateway itself, and any incoming packets that don't correspond to an existing connection are received only by the NAT gateway – they're not implicitly shared across all hosts. (They're also subject to the gateway's firewall rules, which is why you're getting a timeout instead of a regular "Connection refused".)

In order to connect to a specific host from outside, the NAT router needs a specific translation rule – a "port forwarding" rule, which translates all connections to one of the gateway's TCP ports towards your host's internal address.

Usually port-forwarding takes less than a minute to set up, if you have control of the router's configuration. (If it's a residential network, it might even be possible to create a port-forwarding rule by running an UPnP IGD client like `upnpc` from the host.)

Answer (score 0):

To SSH getting past NAT, you do a  connection the other way and then a connection the way you want, within that!

i.e. you SSH from the computer behind NAT, to a computer that is not behind NAT.

And then from that computer that is not behind NAT, you caon connect with whatever protocol SSH or whatever, to that computer so you can do an SSH connection within that existing SSH connection.

It's a reverse tunnel.

Now let's say two computers are behind NAT.

The computer you want to connect from, and the computer you want to connect to. Comp A and C. So you set up a CompB.

Well then you set up the reverse tunnel CompC to CompB.

Then connect A to B, and it gets redirected to CompC.

CompB can be a "VPS" / a computer or virtual computer made available to you by some hosting service.  No NAT issue there.

One might wonder is  it encrypted between A and B. In your case it is because you're sending SSH through. Between B and C would I suppose be double encrypted!